# Callback function to replace setTimeout

Tags: jquery, callback, form-submit

After completing a form submit, I will like to do some action with checkboxes, removing the checked attribute.

In order to avoid the inmediate execution of the action, I use the function setTimeout and it works. This is the code

```
$("#recibosTaller").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.submit(); //
    setTimeout(function(){$(clase).each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {            
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });},100);
 });
```

I suppose that the use of a callback function should be more appropiate. How can we use a callback function for the submit function? Could you provide this code with the use of a callback function?

Comment: The native `submit` method doesn't support callbacks afaik. You could submit the form "manually" via Ajax (and then use the Ajax callback).